# Javascript click event callback not working

Tags: javascript, callback, onclick

I am using javascript to handle click event.
The code is below :

```
function addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag() {

    var anchors =  document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];

        var guid = anchor.attributes.getNamedItem('GUID');
        if(guid)
        {
            anchor.addEventListener("click", onClickLoginPopup);
        }
    }   
}
```

Here I am fetching all anchor tags that has GUID attribute and adding click event listener to it.
But my callback function onClickLoginPopup never gets called.

```
function onClickLoginPopup(e) {
    console.log('onClickLoginPopup');
    e.preventDefault();
    var host = window.location.hostname;

    var url = this.href;    

    var guid = this.attributes.getNamedItem("GUID"); 

    var mainPopup = document.getElementById('popupMain');
    var popupPayment = document.getElementById('popupPayment');



    if( mainPopup == null ) {
        console.log(mainPopup);
    } 
    else if(userID)
    {
        showSocialLoginPopup(); 
        return false;
    }
    if(popupPayment !== null){
        showPaymentPopup();
    }
    //articleLinkClickAction(guid);
    return false;
}
```

Calling Code:

```
function mpwInit() {

    addPopupContents();
    addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag();
}

includeScripts();
window.onload = mpwInit;
```

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling `addClickEventListenerToAllAnchorTag` function ? Have you logged the list of selected anchor elements ? Is it an empty array ? If it is an empty array then you JavaScript code is getting executed before the page loads.

Comment: I am calling it on onload

Comment: It was working earlier fine. But suddenly stopped functioning

Comment: infact even though I am using e.preventDefault it is redirecting me to the URL.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Everything seems to be working fine. Can you have a look at the fiddle and let me know if it is working as expected ?

Comment: Yeah its working as expected. But cant understand whats wrong with my code.

Comment: I assume it is something that has to do with your `onload`. Can you post that code ?

Comment: Earlier the code was working very well. But now it seems something went wrong with it

Comment: Hope the code you have updated is present in body ? That too at last ? If so, try logging _anchors list_ to see whether the selected elements are empty or not.

Comment: I can see list of anchors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74716/discussion-between-vigneswaran-marimuthu-and-mahendrakawde).